# Changed files are not recognised on mounted drive

Tags: 11.04, server, mount

I have ubuntu 11 server installed as a virual machine using vmware fusion. Some of my files are on the mounted drive /mnt/hgfs in order to be shared with my mac.

Everything works fine until I change any of the files on the mounted drive. For example when doing a reboot and then a:

```
$ ll /mnt/hgfs/public/index.php
```

It returns:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 501 dialout 251 2011-08-01 01:59 /mnt/hgfs/public/index.php
```

But when I CHANGE the file on the mounted drive and then again

```
$ ll /mnt/hgfs/public/index.php
```

The output is:

```
ls: cannot access /mnt/hgfs/public/index.php: Invalid argument
```

Whats wrong here?

I mounted the drive with

```
$ sudo mount -t vmhgfs -v -o ro .host:/my-app /mnt/hgfs
```

Comment: Same here with Ubuntu 11.04. Ubuntu 10.04 on the exact same set-up works fine. Hardware config in my case is VMware Fusion-3.1.3-416484, on an iMac OS X v10.7 (same problem with v10.6). I suspect it's more a VMWare problem than Ubuntu but Windows 7 and Ubuntu 10 both work flawlessly on the same set-up. I do a lot of routine networking between Windows/Ubuntu 10/Host iMac daily. Only 11.04 has serious problems. Same problem with either VMWare supplied vmware-tools or open-vm tools, too.

Comment: I can confirm this, I have the same hardware (os x 10.6) and the same vmware fusion version. Have you found any workaround? Currently I am working via SSH/vim on that local machine as I dont want to setup a new 10.04 vm… I noticed that flaw only after I made my whole server setup.

Comment: I´ll give up for now, used another image with ubuntu 10.10 as base and now folder sharing works again. A day of work wasted but whatever.

Comment: This is definitely a problem with VMware's tools, and you should report it as a bug with them. They've been very responsive to me in the past for issues like the one above, even when I report them in pre-release versions of Ubuntu. I'm sure they'd be interested in hearing about it!

Comment: Same problem here. I don't think that it is restricted to VMware fusion though. When I couldn't get it to work under fusion I installed Parallels Desktop (6.0) and I have the same problem there with Ubuntu 11.04

Answer (score 1):

This is how I fixed it:
http://viraj-workstuff.blogspot.com/2013/07/vmware-fusion-permissions-on-shared.html

VMWare should be able to use this fix this for once and all.

1. sudo vim /etc/vmware-tools/services.sh
2. Search for 'vmhgfs_mnt="/mnt/hgfs"'. After this line add: 'vmuser=${VMWARE_MNT_USER:-root}'
3. Then search for 'vmware_exec_selinux "mount -t vmhgfs .host:/ $vmhgfs_mnt"' and replace it with following section:
   uid=`id --user $vmuser`
   gid=`id --group $vmuser`
   vmware_exec_selinux "mount -t vmhgfs .host:/ $vmhgfs_mnt -o uid=$uid,gid=$gid"
4. sudo vim /etc/init/vmware-tools.conf
   Before the "pre-start" and "post-stop" lines add:
   env VMWARE_MNT_USER=[The guest user you want]
5. sudo reboot

Comment: It would be preferable to expand on the link and provide instructions in the answer, just using the link as a reference.